# How to access data from online Oracle Application Express

Tags: jsp, oracle-apex

I am beginner of Oracle Application Express.

I have developed a JSP application. How can I access that data and manipulate that data through my application.

i.e I will need the driver information, user name, password and so on.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an 'online edition'. There is an Oracle Database Express Edition database which you can download and install. There is an online apex.oracle.com application express environment.

If you install the Express Edition, it will prompt for a password for the system account. Using that you can set up a basic schema account with whatever username and password you desire. If you are running the application on the same machine, you shouldn't need a separate client. Otherwise, download the InstantClient, unzip it and follow the instructions.

You can't connect a JSP app to the database behind apex.oracle.com.